# AttributeError: 'tkapp' object has no attribute 'Menu1Button'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python and I'm trying to change dynamically button's text and command to make sub-menus.
here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter

class Display(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.GuiDisplay()

    def GuiDisplay(self):

        self.grid()
        self.geometry("1280x720")
        #self.overrideredirect(True) #uncomment for fullscreen

        """Build the GUI"""

        MessageDisplay = tkinter.Label(self, text = 'No messages from slaves', anchor = 'nw', justify = 'left', relief = 'ridge', font = ("Courier New", 15), bg = '#e4e7e8', fg = '#2980b9')
        MessageDisplay.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = 'wens', ipadx = 2, ipady = 2)

        ClockDisplay = tkinter.Label(self, text = '00:00', relief = 'ridge', font = ("Courier New", 40), bg = '#e4e7e8', fg = '#2980b9')
        ClockDisplay.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = 'wens', ipadx = 2, ipady = 2)

        Menu1Button = tkinter.Button(self, text = 'Ring', command = self.Action(Do = 'Rng'), font = ("Courier New", 20), bg = '#3498db', fg = '#e4e7e8', activebackground = '#2980b9', activeforeground = '#e4e7e8')
        Menu1Button.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'wens', padx = 2, ipadx = 4)

        Menu2Button = tkinter.Button(self, text = 'Toggle holliday mode', command = self.Action(Do = 'SwHolDay'), font = ("Courier New", 20), bg = '#3498db', fg = '#e4e7e8', activebackground = '#2980b9', activeforeground = '#e4e7e8')
        Menu2Button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'wens', padx = 2, ipadx = 4)

        Menu3Button = tkinter.Button(self, text = 'Edit time', command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 2), font = ("Courier New", 20), bg = '#3498db', fg = '#e4e7e8', activebackground = '#2980b9', activeforeground = '#e4e7e8')
        Menu3Button.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'wens', padx = 2, ipadx = 4)

        Menu4Button = tkinter.Button(self, text = 'Add/Edit alarms', command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 3), font = ("Courier New", 20), bg = '#3498db', fg = '#e4e7e8', activebackground = '#2980b9', activeforeground = '#e4e7e8')
        Menu4Button.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'wens', padx = 2, ipadx = 4)

        Menu5Button = tkinter.Button(self, text = 'Shutdown', command = self.Action(Do = 'Shutdwn'), font = ("Courier New", 20), bg = '#3498db', fg = '#e4e7e8', activebackground = '#2980b9', activeforeground = '#e4e7e8')
        Menu5Button.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'wens', padx = 2, ipadx = 4)

        MenuDescription = tkinter.Label(self, text = 'No menu selected.', anchor = 'nw', justify = 'left', relief = 'ridge', font = ("Courier New", 15), bg = '#e4e7e8', fg = '#2980b9')
        MenuDescription.grid(column = 2, columnspan = 2, row = 1, rowspan = 5, sticky = 'wens', ipadx = 2, ipady = 2)

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 3)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight = 3)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight = 3)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight = 1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 10)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight = 18)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight = 18)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight = 18)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight = 18)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight = 18)

    def SetMenu(self, MenuIndex):

        if MenuIndex==1:
            self.Menu1Button.configure(text = 'Ring', command = self.Action(Do = 'Rng'))
            self.Menu2Button.configure(text = 'Toggle holliday mode', command = self.Action(Do = 'SwHolDay'))
            self.Menu3Button.configure(text = 'Edit time', command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 2))
            self.Menu4Button.configure(text = 'Add/Edit alarms', command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 3))
            self.Menu5Button.configure(text = 'Shutdown', command = self.Action(Do = 'Shutdwn'))
        elif MenuIndex==2:
            self.Menu1Button.configure(text = 'Edit hours', command = self.Action(Do = 'ModH'))
            self.Menu2Button.configure(text = 'Edit minutes', command = self.Action(Do = 'ModM'))
            self.Menu3Button.configure(text = 'Edit seconds', command = self.Action(Do = 'ModS'))
            self.Menu4Button.configure(text = 'Internet synchronization', command = self.Action(Do = 'Synch'))
            self.Menu5Button.configure(text = 'Return to menu', command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 1))
        elif MenuIndex==3:
            self.Menu1Button.configure(text = 'Edit hours', command = self.Action(Do = 'ModHA'))
            self.Menu2Button.configure(text = 'Edit minutes', command = self.Action(Do = 'ModMA'))
            self.Menu3Button.configure(text = 'Edit seconds', command = self.Action(Do = 'ModSA'))
            self.Menu4Button.configure(text = 'Switch mode', command = self.Action(Do = 'ChMod'))
            self.Menu5Button.configure(text = 'Return to menu', command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 1))

    def  Action(self, Do):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = Display(None)
        app.title('Web Bell')
        app.mainloop()
```

and the traceback for the error is

```
  File "\\uranus\faure\Bureau\project\webBell.py", line 80, in <module>
    app = Display(None)
  File "\\uranus\faure\Bureau\project\webBell.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.GuiDisplay()
  File "\\uranus\faure\Bureau\project\webBell.py", line 32, in GuiDisplay
    Menu3Button = tkinter.Button(self, text = 'Edit time', command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 2), font = ("Courier New", 20), bg = '#3498db', fg = '#e4e7e8', activebackground = '#2980b9', activeforeground = '#e4e7e8')
  File "\\uranus\faure\Bureau\project\webBell.py", line 64, in SetMenu
    self.Menu1Button.configure(text = 'Edit hours', command = self.Action(Do = 'ModH'))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1867, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: 'tkapp' object has no attribute 'Menu1Button'
```

I guess it come from the "self" in the SetMenu function but I tried without and it still didn't works.

EDIT:
updated code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter

class Display(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.GuiDisplay()

    def GuiDisplay(self):

        self.grid()
        self.geometry("1280x720")
        #self.overrideredirect(True) #uncomment for fullscreen

        """Build the GUI"""

        self.MessageDisplay = tkinter.Label(self, text = 'No messages from slaves', anchor = 'nw', justify = 'left', relief = 'ridge', font = ("Courier New", 15), bg = '#e4e7e8', fg = '#2980b9')
        self.MessageDisplay.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = 'wens', ipadx = 2, ipady = 2)

        self.ClockDisplay = tkinter.Label(self, text = '00:00', relief = 'ridge', font = ("Courier New", 40), bg = '#e4e7e8', fg = '#2980b9')
        self.ClockDisplay.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = 'wens', ipadx = 2, ipady = 2)

        self.Menu1Button = tkinter.Button(self, text = 'Ring', command = self.Action(Do = 'Rng'), font = ("Courier New", 20), bg = '#3498db', fg = '#e4e7e8', activebackground = '#2980b9', activeforeground = '#e4e7e8')
        self.Menu1Button.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'wens', padx = 2, ipadx = 4)

        self.Menu2Button = tkinter.Button(self, text = 'Toggle holliday mode', command = self.Action(Do = 'SwHolDay'), font = ("Courier New", 20), bg = '#3498db', fg = '#e4e7e8', activebackground = '#2980b9', activeforeground = '#e4e7e8')
        self.Menu2Button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'wens', padx = 2, ipadx = 4)

        self.Menu3Button = tkinter.Button(self, text = 'Edit time', command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 2), font = ("Courier New", 20), bg = '#3498db', fg = '#e4e7e8', activebackground = '#2980b9', activeforeground = '#e4e7e8')
        self.Menu3Button.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'wens', padx = 2, ipadx = 4)

        self.Menu4Button = tkinter.Button(self, text = 'Add/Edit alarms', command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 3), font = ("Courier New", 20), bg = '#3498db', fg = '#e4e7e8', activebackground = '#2980b9', activeforeground = '#e4e7e8')
        self.Menu4Button.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'wens', padx = 2, ipadx = 4)

        self.Menu5Button = tkinter.Button(self, text = 'Shutdown', command = self.Action(Do = 'Shutdwn'), font = ("Courier New", 20), bg = '#3498db', fg = '#e4e7e8', activebackground = '#2980b9', activeforeground = '#e4e7e8')
        self.Menu5Button.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'wens', padx = 2, ipadx = 4)

        self.MenuDescription = tkinter.Label(self, text = 'No menu selected.', anchor = 'nw', justify = 'left', relief = 'ridge', font = ("Courier New", 15), bg = '#e4e7e8', fg = '#2980b9')
        self.MenuDescription.grid(column = 2, columnspan = 2, row = 1, rowspan = 5, sticky = 'wens', ipadx = 2, ipady = 2)

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 3)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight = 3)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight = 3)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight = 1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 10)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight = 18)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight = 18)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight = 18)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight = 18)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight = 18)

    def SetMenu(self, MenuIndex):

        if MenuIndex==1:
            self.Menu1Button.configure(text = 'Ring', command = self.Action(Do = 'Rng'))
            self.Menu2Button.configure(text = 'Toggle holliday mode', command = self.Action(Do = 'SwHolDay'))
            self.Menu3Button.configure(text = 'Edit time', command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 2))
            self.Menu4Button.configure(text = 'Add/Edit alarms', command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 3))
            self.Menu5Button.configure(text = 'Shutdown', command = self.Action(Do = 'Shutdwn'))
        elif MenuIndex==2:
            self.Menu1Button.configure(text = 'Edit hours', command = self.Action(Do = 'ModH'))
            self.Menu2Button.configure(text = 'Edit minutes', command = self.Action(Do = 'ModM'))
            self.Menu3Button.configure(text = 'Edit seconds', command = self.Action(Do = 'ModS'))
            self.Menu4Button.configure(text = 'Internet synchronization', command = self.Action(Do = 'Synch'))
            self.Menu5Button.configure(text = 'Return to menu', command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 1))
        elif MenuIndex==3:
            self.Menu1Button.configure(text = 'Edit hours', command = self.Action(Do = 'ModHA'))
            self.Menu2Button.configure(text = 'Edit minutes', command = self.Action(Do = 'ModMA'))
            self.Menu3Button.configure(text = 'Edit seconds', command = self.Action(Do = 'ModSA'))
            self.Menu4Button.configure(text = 'Switch mode', command = self.Action(Do = 'ChMod'))
            self.Menu5Button.configure(text = 'Return to menu', command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 1))

    def  Action(self, Do):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = Display(None)
        app.title('Web Bell')
        app.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are a lot of errors in this code: `self.GuiDisplay.Menu5Button` will not do anything as `GuiDisplay` is a function and has no return value and no attribute called `Menu5Button`.

Comment: thanks, just corrected that, I forget to remove GuiDisplay in this part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not defined `Menu1Button` as a class attribute, so it is only scoped inside your `__init__`. It should be defined as:

```
self.Menu1Button = tkinter.Button(self, text = 'Ring', command = self.Action(Do = 'Rng'), font = ("Courier New", 20), bg = '#3498db', fg = '#e4e7e8', activebackground = '#2980b9', activeforeground = '#e4e7e8')
self.Menu1Button.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'wens', padx = 2, ipadx = 4)
```

The same goes for all the other widgets defined inside your constructor.

EDIT:

So now that that first problem is fixed the issue becomes much clearer. You are defining the command attribute of your widgets incorrectly.

For example, for `self.Menu3Button` you define the command as `self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 2)`. In python this will try and execute the function `self.SetMenu` with the argument `2` (sidebar: you don't need to do `MenuIndex=2`, just `2` is fine) when it first gets to it. This causes the function `SetMenu` to execute before `Menu3Button` has been defined as a class attribute. Hence python cannot find the attribute and you get an `AttributeError`.

The `command` passed to the widget should be a function instance. For example:

```
# an example function
def printit(val):
    print val

# This is NOT valid
command = printit("hello!")

# This is valid
command = lambda:printit("hello!")
```

In the valid case we are passing a partial function (i.e. a half formed function where the arguments are already attached):

```
In [29]: printit("direct call")
direct call

In [30]: partial_printit = lambda:printit("partial call")

In [31]: partial_printit()
partial call
```

So in your case:

```
command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 2)
```

becomes

```
command = lambda:self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 2)
```

This is the same for all the `command` keywords for all your widgets.

For more info on lambda functions, see here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions

Comment: it gives me an error AttributeError: 'tkapp' object has no attribute 'Menu3Button'

Comment: As I said the same problem applies to all the widgets defined in your constructor. They should all be `self.Menu3Button`, `self.Menu4Button`, `self.MenuDescription` etc.

Comment: Could you post your updated code in your question. Do not overwrite the original code, but add the new code below.